# Objective-C: Delegate system not correctly working in Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates, uibutton, nsuserdefaults

Bellow I have a delegation system that hides a button and then saves wherever the button is hide or not in a `NSUserDefault`. However for some reason it is not working can anyone help?

**Here I have the levelComplete code...
.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "levelComplete.h"
#import "LevelSelector.h"

@interface levelComplete : UIViewController{
  }
 @property (nonatomic, strong) id<CustomDelegate> delegatePpty;

 @end
```

**.m**

```
@implementation levelComplete
@synthesize delegatePpty;

-(void)someAction
 {
[self.delegatePpty hideUnhidebutton:YES];//Call the delegate method to execute
 }


 - (void)viewDidLoad
   {
     [super viewDidLoad];
     // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
     [self someAction]; // Here I call my action
   }
@end
```

**Here I have the leveSelector code...**

**.h**

```
  @protocol CustomDelegate <NSObject>
  -(void)hideUnhidebutton:(BOOL)value;
  @end

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "levelComplete.h"
#import "LevelSelector.h"

@interface LevelSelector : UIViewController <CustomDelegate>{        

}

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIButton *level1;

@end
```

**.m**

```
@implementation LevelSelector
@synthesize level1;

-(void)hideUnhidebutton:(BOOL)value
 {
  [self.level1 setHidden:value];
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:value] forKey:@"YourVariableKey"];
  }

 - (void)viewDidLoad
   {
    [super viewDidLoad];
     // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib

     NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
     BOOL restoredBoolValue = [[defaults objectForKey:@"YourVariableKey"] boolValue];
    }
@end
```

Thanks in advance !!!

**Edit**

```
Thanks for all of your help I have now got the code to correctly function
```

Comment: Well, you are not saving `NSUserDefaults`, it's very strange to use `NSUserDefaults` for this and you probably have problems with the order in which the methods are called.

Comment: Also, delegates generally are weak (not retained).

Comment: Have you tried calling synchronize on NSUserDefaults after setting the property?

Comment: Yes I have tried but will try agin

Comment: As an aside, it looks like you have your `levelComplete` (which doesn't follow class naming conventions) updating a control on another view controller's view. That's not great MVC structure and, worse, if you're supporting iOS versions prior to 6, that's not an entirely safe practice (in low memory situations, that prior view may have been unloaded). It's better to update the model backing that other view controller, and have `viewWillAppear` update the controls.

Comment: Place the code for levelComplete instance creation in LevelSelector class.

Comment: Thanks for all of your help I have now got the code to currently function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think you are missing something at delegation,once see this

delegateclass.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@protocol CustomDelegate <NSObject>
-(void)hideUnhidebutton:(BOOL)value;
@end

@interface delegateclass : UIViewController <CustomDelegate>{        
id<CustomDelegate> delegate;
}
@property(retain) id delegate;

-(void)someMethod;
@end
```

delegateclass.m

```
 #import "delegateclass.h"

 @implementation delegateclass
 @synthesize delegate;


 -(void)someMethod {

   NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
   BOOL restoredBoolValue = [[defaults objectForKey:@"YourVariableKey"] boolValue];
   [[self delegate] hideUnhidebutton:restoredBoolValue];

   }
 @end
```

TestViewController.h

```
 #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
 #import "delegateclass.h"

 @interface TestViewController : UIViewController{
  delegateclass *delegateclassObj;
 }
  @property (nonatomic, strong) id<CustomDelegate> delegatePpty;
  @property (nonatomic, strong) UIButton *level1;
  @end
```

TestViewController.m

```
   #import "TestViewController.h"
   @implementation TestViewController
   @synthesize delegatePpty,level1;

  - (void)viewDidLoad
   {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    delegateclassObj = [[delegateclass alloc]init];
    [delegateclassObj setDelegate:self];
    [delegateclassObj someMethod];
   }
  //Implementaion for Delegatemethod......

   -(void)hideUnhidebutton:(BOOL)value
   {
   [self.level1 setHidden:value];
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
   [defaults setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:value] forKey:@"YourVariableKey"];
   }
   @end
```

sorry i dnt know exactly what your theme is,but here delegete method (hideUnhidebutton:) must calls.

Hope it will be helpful to you..

Answer (score 1):

Things to check

When creating instance of levelComplete

```
[levelCompleteInstance setDelegatePpty:self];
```

synchronize NSUserDefaults

```
- (BOOL)synchronize
```